# How should I clear these errors and why are they there?

Tags: c, compiler-errors, c-strings, function-call

assignment to ‘int’ from ‘int (*)()’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Werror=int-conversion]

To give some context:

```
int functionA(){
    int a;
    ....//some operation on a
    return a;
}

void functionB(){
    int b = functionA;
}
```

the error message appears at line

```
int b = functionA;
```

The other error I keep getting is:
error: expected expression before ‘]’ token

to give context:

```
struct cat{
    char name[10];
} cats[10];

void functionC(char name[]){
    cats[0].name = name[];
}
```

the error occurs at cats[0].name = name[];

Comment: @M.M Yh i did mean to call functionA, is that not the way to do it tho since functionA doesnt require any parameters? And second case i assumed you can just equate an char[] to another char[] since they are both strings, bad habit from java,  strcpy should do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the error message appears at line

```
int b = functionA;
```

You forget the parenthesis:

```
int b = functionA();
```

In C, prefer `int functionA(void)` (function without arguments) instead of `int functionA()` (function with unspecified number of arguments)

---

```
struct cat{
    char name[10];
} cats[10];

void functionC(char name[]){
    cats[0].name = name[];
}
```

Here `cats[0].name` is an array, array names are non-modifiable lvalues, instead:

```
strcpy(cats[0].name, name);
```

or better yet:

```
snprintf(cats[0].name, sizeof cats[0].name, "%s", name); // Avoid buffer overflows
```

Comment: ah yes yes, sprintf was what i did earlier before i had to completely redo my data structure, never seen snprint before tho, will have a google now.  Also, if int function(void) is preferred, calling it is still empty parenthesis right? e.g. int a = funtion() and not int a = function(void);

Comment: @PapaSheng, yes, the call should not include the `void` keyword, use `int a = funtion();`

Answer (score 2):

In this statement

```
int b = functionA;
```

the right hand side operand has the type int ( * )() that is it is a function pointer. It seems you mean a call of the function.

```
int b = functionA();
```

And arrays do not have the assignment operator. Write

```
void functionC( const char name[] ){
    strcpy( cats[0].name, name );
}
```

Comment: Ah.. i see hahah jesus my brain is fried after trying to debug for the whole day, thanks man.